# How to get the url of logo image?

Tags: plugin-development

How can I access the logo image URL inside my javascript file? is there any WordPress function that I can use to localize the variable?

Comment: You can't easily get WordPress data from inside a JavaScript file, no, sorry: the easiest way might be to add some extra script on the page to set a JS variable with the URL and then your script file can use that variable.

Comment: But I'm not completely clear what the situation is here: do you have the logo on the page already? Then you could identify it in HTML with a class or ID, then your script could read the URL from that. Or does your theme not put the logo on the page, and it's up to your script to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This helped me.

```php
wp_localize_script( 'ap-otp-modal', 'ap_otp', [
    'logourl' => wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ) , 'full' )
]);
```